# DDD Value Object shared by multiple entities

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I've been studying about DDD and have some questions in respect to Value Object.
I created value objects for Email, Phone and Address then added validation to them by using their constructor. So far so good.
The thing is that I need the same Value Objects for different aggregate roots. Let's say I have 3 aggregate roots which need the same value objects (Customer, Doctor, Receptionist)

I've seen an example that was created one Address for each aggregate root, but I didn't want to repeat code as those ValueObjects also contains validations.
Can I share them among the aggregate roots? If so, how do you structure it?

Answer (score 2):

Email, phone and address are concepts that don't belong to your domain, that I guess it is something related to hospitals or the like.

They would belong to another domain that we could call "people" or something like that, where you could define contact information concepts like those you mention (email, phone, address).

How to integrate with that domain? Well since they are concepts frequently used in many contexts, you could put them in a shared kernel.

So to the question regarding the structure, which I guess you are referring to folders, put them outside the structure of your "hospital" bounded context.

Create a shared kernel (concepts shared by several domains) with a folder called person/contact and put there your email, phone and address value objects. The shared kernel is like a library you use.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there's nothing wrong with reusing value object types under multiple types of entities or aggregate roots. You just avoid code duplication.

The same isn't true for the instances. Two entities (of same or different type) should never share the same instance of a value object. This is true for both in-memory objects and persisted data.

If you have multiple bounded contexts, value objects like Email/Phone/Address are good candidates for shared kernel. They are small and self-contained, with low chances of becoming "god objects" that know/do too much.

In code, you can represent a Value Object as an immutable `struct`. This would reinforce the characteristics of Value Object in DDD.

In a relational database, an object like Address can be represented by the Address table, with a unique key column. Tables representing entities can have foreign keys to the Address table (one-to-one relation). In a one-to-many relation, when entities have collections of Addresses, a many-to-many relation tables can be introduced, one relation table per containing entity.

In a document database, value objects can often be embedded in the documents of containing entities.

Of course, these are just general considerations, these decisions depend on your specific case.

Comment: How can I structure it? I mean, I just need to place these value objects somewhere in Domain so that all entities/aggregate roots which need it can refer to it?
Is there a correct way/structure to do that with DDD?